# How to evaluate the given polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)=x^5+x^2+1$ have roots ${x_1}$, ${x_2}$, ${x_3}$, ${x_4}$ and ${x_5}$. Let $g(x)=x^2-2$, then find the value of
$$L=\prod_{i=1}^5 g(x_i)-30 g\big(\prod_{i=1}^5 x_i\big).$$

My attempts were taking an equation whose roots are y = g ( ${x_i}$ ),
which is y = $x^2 - 2$ and then substituted x = $\sqrt{y-2}$ in p(x), however im unsure if this is heading in the right direction, any better alternates will be appreciated..

Comment: What have you tried? Edit your question including with your attempts.

Comment: Do you know about [Vieta's Formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)?

Comment: Hint: As pointed out by @DS use Vieta's formula to determine the value of $\prod_{i=1}^5 x_i$. Now use that $g(x)=(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})$ together with the fact that $p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^5(x-x_i)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** As hinted already in the comments,
$$L = p(\sqrt2)p(-\sqrt2) - 30 g(-1)=(4\sqrt2+3)(3-4\sqrt2)+30=7$$